# Remove similar items from List

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The following data is returned from an SQL View:

```
Name        CandidateID         Filled
Tom Jones   1003436             2014-05-09  07:13:53.087
Tom Jones   1003436             2014-05-09  07:13:18.957
Ed  Harris  1421522             2014-05-09  08:17:20.234
```

I only want the one Tom Jones record with the latest Filled time. How can I achive this in C#/LINQ while getting or after getting data from server?

Comment: Please specify what you consider "similar" and what not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var q = from n in table
        group n by new {n.CandidateID,n.Name} into g
        select new 
        {
            CandidateID = g.Key.CandidateID, 
            Name = g.Key.Name, 
            Filled = g.Max(t=>t.Filled)
        };
```

**Test class**

```
class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CandidateID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Filled { get; set; }
}
```

**Test case**

```
var ls=new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo(){Name="Tom Jones",CandidateID=1003436,
                  Filled=DateTime.Parse("2014-05-09  07:13:53.087")},
        new Foo(){Name="Tom Jones",CandidateID=1003436,
                  Filled=DateTime.Parse("2014-05-09  07:13:18.957")},
        new Foo(){Name="Ed  Harris",CandidateID=1421522,
                  Filled=DateTime.Parse("2014-05-09  08:17:20.234")}
    };
    var q = 
        (from n in ls
        group n by new {n.CandidateID,n.Name} into g
        select new 
        {
            CandidateID = g.Key.CandidateID, 
            Name = g.Key.Name, 
            Filled = g.Max(t=>t.Filled)
        });
```

**Output**

```
CandidateID     Name           Filled 
1003436         Tom Jones      09/05/2014 7:13:53 AM 
1421522         Ed  Harris     09/05/2014 8:17:20 AM
```

Comment: exactly same piece of code which i was typing :D Cheers.

Comment: I think you should filter group which are `Count` > 1 to get only the duplicate data. Correct me if I was wrong

Comment: My bad, I misread OP question and thought that he wants to delete duplicate data from database, turn out he only wants to filter his view. Sorry :). And good approach by the way.

Comment: Yeah. The OP want's to filter away the duplicates. Not get the duplicates. I update the answer with a Test case

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = from n in table
        group n by n.CandidateID into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Filled).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need Group by as shown below

```
var distinctItems = ls.GroupBy(x => x.CandidateID).Select(y => y.First());
```